# How to bring a link or anchor tag in Json?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

An example is populating a angular ui grid with json data and it working fine

```
plnkr.co/edit/xBvc4094CIu6oGDZXZx7?p=preview
```

However not sure how to have a download link or link for external source in one of the column in json.

```
example, download link with <a href....>Download Link</a>
```

In datatables,  supports  however how to provide the same in angular ui grid via json data.

Thanks.

Comment: please elaborate your requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Cell Template `cellTemplate` to generate the column with hyperlink, and `{{row.entity.link}}` to fetch the link from JSON property (`link` is the property name in the sample JSON). Sample below.

```
columnDefs: [{
        name: 'FirstName'
      }, {
        name: 'LastName'
      }, {
        name: 'Job'
      }, {
        name: 'Hyperlink',
        cellTemplate: '<div>' +
          '  <a href="{{row.entity.link}}">Click me</a>' +
          '</div>'
      }],
data: [{
        "FirstName": "Sonny",
        "LastName": "Jayet",
        "Job": "Stack Overflow User",
        "link": "https://www.google.com"
      }, {
        "FirstName": "Tim",
        "LastName": "Harker",
        "Job": "Stack Overflow User",
        "link": "https://stackoverflow.com"
      }]
```

I hope this is what you are looking for, and this solves your problem.